# Examples of strongly continuous measure-valued functions

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact geodesic metric space and let $P_p(X)$ be the set of all finite Borel measure on X with finite $p^{th}$ moment.  We equip $P_p(X)$ with the total variation topology metric.  What are some examples of functions:
$$
f:[0,1]^k \rightarrow P_p(X)
$$
which are (total-variation) continuous; kere $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$?

Comment: I guess you want some "special" example, since a plain example needs  no particular features of $\mathcal{P}_p(X)$, besides convexity. Choose e.g. $n$ measures $\mu_j\in\mathcal{P}_p(X)$ and  $n$ continuous functions, $\alpha_j:[0,1]^k\to[0,+\infty)$, for $j=1\dots n$, with $\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_j(x)\neq0$ for all $x$. Then define $f(x):=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_j(x)\mu_j}{\|\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_j(x)\mu_j\|}\in \mathcal{P}_p(X)$.

Comment: @PietroMajer What do you mean by a "plain example"..and convexity?

Comment: Just saying that since $C:=\mathcal{P}_p(X)$ is a convex subset of a normed space, one can build $C$-valued continuous maps as continuous convex combinations  of some given elements of it .

Comment: Oh ya, ofcourse (I thought we were chatting about something different for a second).  I guess.. the question I'm trying to formulation is... is there a "nice" description/characterization of continuous functions from $[0,1]^k$ into $\mathscr{M}(X)$ with total-variation norm?